# Replace " with \" in C# String

Tags: c#

I need to take a string that was originally read in from a text file and prepend a backslash to any and all double quotes found in the string. I tried

```
String myString = inputString.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

and even

```
String myString = "";
foreach (Char Character in inputString)
    if (Character == '"')
        myString += "\\\"";
    else
        myString += Character;
```

However, I still keep getting the same string back as I received (no backslashes in front of the double quotes).

In my example, one value of inputString would show up in the debugger as "div id="loader"", and I want the resulting myString to be "div id=\"loader\"" as seen in the debugger.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve my desired results?

Comment: Might just be a typo on the question, but you're missing the last `"` on your first example.

Comment: To explain, Robert means this should be `inputString.Replace("\"", "\\\"");` which does exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Marc: According to the debugger, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `+=` operator incorrectly.

Try this:

```
String myString = inputString.Replace("\"", @"\""");
```

Comment: The problem is that Replace() (or my loop) doesn't seem to see the double quotes in the input string as being double quotes if what I'm seeing in the debugger is anything to go by.

Comment: It probably isn't.  The code in my answer does what you were looking for.

Comment: I'll take your word for it. In the mean time, I've found another way to get what I want by editing the text file where the input string originates (which serves as an input script for an automation test engine) and an XML file (which defines script variables).

Answer (score 2):

> value of inputString would show up in the debugger as ...

Don't trust the debugger. It honors the escape sequences in the string. The code (or at least one of your attempts) is probably doing exactly what it's supposed to.

If you use your first sample (post-edit) and check the output in a respectable text editor, it should work just fine.

Comment: Regarding the unfinished string literal, that was a type in the question, which I just fixed. As for the debugger honouring escape sequences, that doesn't always seem to be the case. My code compares the strings that it gets with strings that it gets from another source, and I see the string that my example is supposed to match show up with the backslashes before the quotes. The differences cause the two strings to not match.

Comment: One source is a plain text file, and the other is from the XML in a web page. I seriously doubt that either is using smart quotes or other weirdness.